# Positive integers $n$ satisfying $\omega(n)<\omega(n+1)<\omega(n+2)$

Tags: number-theory

Let $ \omega(n) $ denote the no. of distinct prime divisors of $n$ , then does there exist infinitely many positive integers $n$ satisfying $\omega(n)<\omega(n+1)<\omega(n+2)$  ?

Comment: On the standard conjectures, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $n$ is prime, $n+1$ is twice a prime, and $n+2$ is 15 times a prime. I don't know offhand whether there is an unconditional proof.

Comment: It is not very easy even finding an example. I think that $n=62$ may be the first. Maybe $n=2^k-2$ with $k$ composite are good candidates.

Comment: See this posting at MO, it discusses a generalization of your problem. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171549/in-which-orders-can-the-numbers-of-prime-factors-of-consecutive-integers-be